# numpy.reshape breaks when dealing with a view of a big size

Tags: python, numpy

I have an initial NumPy array of size `(512,512,100)` of type `np.float64` and then I use [view_as_windows](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) function to get an array of size `(499,499,100,64,64)`. This function returns a view that consumes much less memory than an actual NumPy array. I want to reshape the view to `(499*499*100,64,64)`. Using the regular `np.reshape` function, it takes too much time trying to reshape the array, and then it breaks due to trying to convert it to an actual NumPy array. I tried the following, and none of them works:

```
#gs.shape gives (499,499,100,64,64)
gs.shape = (gs.shape[0]*gs.shape[1]*gs.shape[2],64,64,)
gs = np.reshape(gs,(gs.shape[0]*gs.shape[1]*gs.shape[2],64,64,))
gs = gs.reshape(gs.shape[0]*gs.shape[1]*gs.shape[2],64,64,)
```

What is the correct way to change the view without actually causing memory overload?

Comment: That's an array of 800 gigabytes.  Do you REALLY have that stored in memory?

Comment: @TimRoberts I think the caveat is in my recent edit. I think I have a view that I need to reshape and not an actual NumPy array.

Comment: `view_as_windows` makes a `view`, expanding the dimensions by playing games with the strides.  But any `reshape` has to make a copy, and can easily result in a memory error.  This function or `as_strided` warns about this.  What is `gs.strides`?

Comment: @hpaulj right. I paid attention to it after I submitted my question. I think the question now is how to change the view shape without causing a memory error.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: One of the benefits of `reshape` on an array is that it doesn't have to make a copy -- it just changes the "view" of the list of numbers.  But when you reshape a view, that forces it to create an entire array.  It's kind of like quantum mechanics -- the memory doesn't exist until you force it into existence with the reshape.  What you ask cannot be done.

Comment: If all you need is the final 3d view , play with `as_strided`.

Comment: @QuangHoang, I don't think there's a way of getting this kind of windowing with a 3d `as_strided`.  He's creating windows from the first 2 dimensions, leaving the 3rd untouched.  `sliding_window_view` uses `as_strided`, but takes care of a lot of the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to do this reshape?

Your starting array (with a small dtype):

```
In [100]: arr = np.ones((512,512,100), 'int8')    
In [101]: arr.nbytes, arr.strides
Out[101]: (26214400, (51200, 100, 1))
```

Using the `view_as_windows` as ported to the numpy core:

```
In [102]: new = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr,(64,64),(0,1))

In [103]: new.shape, new.strides
Out[103]: ((449, 449, 100, 64, 64), 
          (51200, 100, 1, 51200, 100))

In [105]: new.nbytes/1e9        # the number of elements (memory if copy)
Out[105]: 82.5757696
```

Note that the `arr` final dimension, 100, is now 3rd; in the `view` is still has a single element stride.

Effectively the first dim, 512, has been 'split' between axis 0 and 3; and the 2nd 512, axis (1,4).

To get the shape, (499*499*100,64,64), strides would have to be (? , 51200, 100).  I'm not an expert on `as_strided`, but have enough experience to say there's no way of reworking the first 3 strides (51200, 100, 1) into one.

Let's remove the size 100 dimension to simplify things a bit.

```
In [106]: arr = np.ones((512,512), 'int8')
In [107]: arr.strides
Out[107]: (512, 1)
```

The windowed:

```
In [108]: new = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr,(64,64),(0,1))
In [109]: new.shape, new.strides
Out[109]: ((449, 449, 64, 64), (512, 1, 512, 1))
```

and its 3d reshape (a copy):

```
In [110]: new1 = new.reshape(-1,64,64)    
In [112]: new1.shape, new1.strides
Out[112]: ((201601, 64, 64), (4096, 64, 1))
```

Comment: I have a 3D image and I want to pass 64x64 patches taken from a 2D slice (In my case 100 slices which is the z dimension) to a neural network. Each patch is taken by moving a sliding window of size 64x64 and with a step size equal to 1 either in the x dimension or y dimension. It is like a nested for loop over x and y dimensions.

Comment: If you slice `gs`, you may get something that is small enough to copy, e.g. `gs[i,:,:,:,:]` or `gs[:,i,:,:,:]`.  It will still be large.  But your NN probably has to work in batches anyways.